# How to get acess to the query argument followed after a questionmark?

Tags: reactjs, api, express

After searching for a product inside a search box, my app executes a get request on

> "localhost/api/products?searchword".

Now i want to build an express api, that searches for the searchword inside my db.
How do i get access to the searchword?

I tried with **req.query.name** but it only works with a link like

> "localhost/api/products?name=searchword".

How do i get access with my specific link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an express API endpoint that does exactly that.

I call it using this URL structure: `/blog/search?q=some+search+string`

```
export const blogSearch: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const queryString = (req.query.q || "");
  // ...
}
```

In order to use `req.query`, you should use the `?key1=value1,key2=value2` structure.

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

[image]

If you want to manually parse the `queryString`, you can use `req.url` and you'll get the `/api/products?searchword`, so you can split it on the `?` the read your `searchWord`.

Comment: So do i have to use the key structure? Wouldnt it work without it?

Comment: See the last part of my answer. You can use `req.url` and parse it yourself to get your `searchWord`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will encounter the same problem, so i want to post my code that worked

```
router.get('/',
expressAsyncHandler( async (req, res)=> {
    const name =  req.url.split('?')[1] || "";
    console.log(name);
    const nameFilter= name ? { title: {$regex: name, $options: 'i'} } : {};
    const products = await Product.find({
      ...nameFilter,
    }).populate();
    res.send(products);
})
);
```